# How to get spacing while making form in javascript?

Tags: javascript, css

I want adequate alignment of my form attributes. I tried using CSS, but dont know how to use it in javascript. I am new to development so any help will be appreciated.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    function nextformdisplay() 
    {
        var noee =document.getElementById('noe').value;
        // document.getElementById('noe').value=noee-1;
        var i;
        for(i=0;i<noee;i++)
        {
            var btn = document.createElement("TEXT");
            var t = document.createTextNode("EVENT NAME:  ");
            btn.appendChild(t);
            document.body.appendChild(btn);
            var x = document.createElement("INPUT");
            x.setAttribute("type", "text");
            document.body.appendChild(x);
            linebreak = document.createElement("br");
            document.body.appendChild(linebreak);
            var btn1 = document.createElement("TEXT");
            var t1 = document.createTextNode("EVENT TIME:");
            btn1.appendChild(t1);
            document.body.appendChild(btn1);
            var x1 = document.createElement("INPUT");
            x1.setAttribute("type", "text");
            x1.value="HH:MM:SS";
            document.body.appendChild(x1);
            linebreak = document.createElement("br");
            document.body.appendChild(linebreak);
            var btn2 = document.createElement("TEXT");
            var t2 = document.createTextNode("PLAYER NAME:");
            btn2.appendChild(t2);
            document.body.appendChild(btn2);
            var x2 = document.createElement("INPUT");
            x2.setAttribute("type", "text");
            document.body.appendChild(x2);
            linebreak = document.createElement("p");
            document.body.appendChild(linebreak);
        }
   }
</script>
```

Comment: The easiest way to do css in JavaScript is usually through a library like jquery. You might also want to look at the css framework jquery-ui I believe it has some grid options that would make this easier

Comment: Why not add a class and style that with normal CSS?

Comment: The easiest solution would be to use a CSS library such as [Pure CSS](http://purecss.io/start/). And using a form template would be much easier than generating a form in script as you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

`Define CSS classes` as you Desire and append these classes to them via JavaScript as you wish.
You can als.o use element IDs or inline css but Using CSS classes makes your life easier

e.g

css

```
.my-spacing-class{
    padding:100px;

    /* Other properties go here*/
}
```

javascript

```
 var btn = document.createElement("TEXT");
 btn.className += " my-spacing-class";
```

NOTE : The `[SPACE]` before `my-spacing-class` is intentional!!!!